# Why doesn't this block of code work?

Tags: javascript, scope, iife

I've mocked up some code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/g6f10nke/)

```
var common = common || {};

(function(NAMESPACE) {

  NAMESPACE = {
    isIE: function() {
        return true;
    }
  };

  main();

})(common);

function main() {
    console.log(common.isIE());
  return 'Hello, World!';
}
```

I would like to understand a couple of things,

1) Why isn't this working, I guess it has something to do with how scoping is "decided" and IIFE, but not entirely sure.

2) How to make this code work?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @JesperHøjer well, the iife on top represents my helper functions, which are wrapped in an iife, and when I try to access the functions outside, I get an error saying `common.isIE` is undefined

Comment: Because you are not adding anything to the "common"-object?

Comment: Well, `function main(..)` is outside the IIFE.

Comment: `main` uses the `common` you define to be `var common = common || {};` not the `NAMESPACE` object you create. (Once you give `NAMESPACE` as a parameter `x` to function `main(x)` and use `console.log(x.isIE());` your call works.

Comment: `NAMESPACE.isIE = function() {}` is what you need. Your existing code sets `NAMESPACE` to refer to a different object, which doesn't change which object `common` refers to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`common` which passed as argument named `NAMESPACE` needs to be extended instead of assigning new value.

So `Object.assign` can help here.

```
var common = common|| {};

(function(NAMESPACE) {

  Object.assign(NAMESPACE,{
    isIE: function() {
        return true;
    }
  });

  main();

})(common);

function main() {
    console.log(common.isIE());
  return 'Hello, World!';
}
```

Comment: Will `$.extend` work too? coz IE doesn't suppoer `Object.assign` yet

Answer (score 0):

When you are passing an object as an argument in JS, you should remember that you are passing "by-value" the reference of it.

Creating a new object in literal notation and assigning it to the argument like this,

```
NAMESPACE = {
    isIE: function() {
        return true;
    }
  };
```

can only point the argument to the new object - not to the object of the reference you passed the argument by.

If you had said,

```
NAMESPACE.isIE = function() {}
```

it would work.